# How to use Selenium webdriver to save webpage as PDF?

Tags: selenium, pdf, printing

I am currently using selenium (in java) to automatically navigate through webpages in hopes of saving their contents to the local drive in PDF format.

However, I am struggling to find a method to save a webpage in PDF format automatically (like using ctrl-p/command-p in a chrome window and then saving as PDF). Is there any way to use selenium to perform such a task?

There is also a print button on screen to do a similar thing but my understanding is that selenium cannot control the popup window as it is an OS native popup. Essentially, I need to have a print-to-PDF method in order to save a webpage as a PDF.

I have access to multiple browsers and their web drivers. I will be working on a Windows computer.

Comment: find a framework to translate xml/html to pdf and use it with page.source

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot do that, because the save dialog is a OS dialog. (Not Browser.)

You would need something like **AutoIt** to interact with that.

Alternatively, Selenium has a screenshot functionality that will save the visible part of the viewport as an image.